# Meteor no password signup

Tags: meteor

With Meteor can I configure Accounts.ui.config to have no email and password sign up? I have it configured to use third party services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `accounts-password` by running in your project directory

```
meteor remove accounts-password
```

and it should automatically adjust itself to stop accepting email/password logins and signups for this.